# How to make angularJS ng-model work with objects in select elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with ng-model on a `select` element when passing an object from `option` elements. So, imagine we have an array of columns from a table called `columns` (the table's definition) and we'd like to creat some filters upon this definition

```
var columns = [
  {name: 'Account ID',    type: 'numeric'},
  {name: 'Full name',     type: 'text'},
  {name: 'Date of birth', type: 'date'},
  {name: 'Active',        type: 'boolean'}
  // and so on
];

var filters = [{}];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-field" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
  <select ng-model="filter">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose filter</option>
    <option ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-value="column">{{column.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" ng-model="filter.value">
</div>
```

As you can see, I'd like that `filter` to get the value of `column` and to add specific data in it, so at a certain moment, my filter could be like:

```
[
  {name: 'Account ID', type: 'numeric', value: 123},
  {name: 'Active', type: 'boolean', value: 'Yes'}
]
```

Anyway, I'm not sure this is the way of doing this, but I'd like to know how can I achieve this behavior, withour writing to much js code in the controller.

I did some workaround to get this done using `ng-change`, passing the `filter` and the `column.name`, find the column in the `columns` array, get the `type` property, update the `filter`, but I really think that there is a simpler answer to this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) to bind the selected object to a model:

```
<div class="form-field" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
   <select ng-options="column.name for column in columns" ng-model="filter.value">
         <option value="" disabled>Choose filter</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" ng-model="filter.value.name">
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3ojySE0x6XbDwHkCD7u?p=preview)

**Updated answer:**

```
<div class="form-field" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
   <select ng-options="column.name for column in columns" ng-model="filters[$index]">
     <option value="" disabled>Choose filter</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" ng-model="filters[$index].name">
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated that plunker to use 1.1.5 and it still works fine.

Comment: Hmmm, wierd... it works on plunker but not on my local machine. Anyway... why does it work when binded to `filter.value` but not directly on `filter`? Somehow I need the same structure as the table's definition :)

Comment: It's due to how javascript behaves when setting values on child scopes. It's a bit much to explain in a comment, so see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). To get around this you can use the `$index` property of an ng-repeat loop to set the value. See the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3ojySE0x6XbDwHkCD7u?p=preview).

Comment: Great! This is what I wanted... Now it works, thanks a lot! I've tried something like this but since I was using `<option ng-repeat="...">` and creates a new scope, it's difficult to achieve this. Now, using `ng-options` on `<select>` with `ng-model="filters[$index]"`, works like I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you possibly assist with a similar issue I'm having
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163118/can-we-use-a-ngmodel-directive-with-an-object-property