# Selecting an option by default

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am struggling with the following piece of code.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Select something below</h1>
    <select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
    <h3>The selected item:</h3>
    <pre>{{selectedItem | json}}</pre>
    <h3>The inner html of the select:</h3>
    <pre id="options" class="prettify html"></pre>
  </body>
```

and in js

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 3, name: 'blah' }];

  $scope.selectedItem = { id: 3, name: 'blah' };

});
```

I have a selected item by default. But it doesn't show up in the selection while the page loads.

I have provided my code in the following link

http://plnkr.co/edit/FlESsL?p=preview

In the given example the dropdown  should by default select the item `blah`.

TIA
Mobin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is update your angularjs version, then you can simply follow the angular [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) examples.

In the provided link they use `track by` to display the correct object, I took the liberty of editing their example plunker and added your code [Here it is!](http://plnkr.co/edit/UUIwlSdryKCwfJHOsRg9?p=preview)

as you can see, the only thing I added to your code was `track by item.id`

Comment: Haa i didnt see that coming. Thanks. I did try with `track by` but forgot to check for the version.

Comment: @MobinSkariya glad I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"></select>
```

and:

```
$scope.selectedItem = 3;
```

Comment: I want to bind `selectedItem` to an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921930/how-to-make-angular-ng-model-work-with-objects-in-select-elements

Comment: Sorry i didnt find the link helpful. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Before putting question did you go through - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Just make below change in your controller -

$scope.selectedItem =  $scope.items[0];