# Can we use a [(ngModel)] directive with an object property?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to use an object like the following:

```js
  private userInfo: IUser;


export interface IUser {
  userId: string;
  email: string;
  photoUrl?: string;
  displayName: string;
  location?: string;
  bio?: string;
  intDestination?: string[];
  dateOfBirth?: any;
  education?: string;
  gender?: string;
  userSetting?: {turnOnNotify: boolean};
}
```

```html
    <ion-card color="light">
      <p>{{userInfo?.displayName}}</p>
      <input size="70" ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options' [(ngModel)]="userInfo.location" #placesRef="ngx-places"
        (onAddressChange)="handleCityChange($event)" />
    </ion-card>
```

But the ngModel doesn't like the . notation identifying the object property

```js
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at ProfilePage_Template (template.html:28)
```

Is there a way to use the object's property in ngModel?

Comment: I see what the problem is, the page loads before i'm able to pull the information and the object is null.  I'm not sure how to prevent that given I'm performing the call in ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

this is because  **userInfo** is private, if you want access userInfo on Html it need be public.

```
 userInfo: IUser;
```

Comment: still getting Cannot read property 'location' of undefined even if I change it to public.

It's working in       <p>{{userInfo?.displayName}}</p> just not in the ngModel